# Why the following formula slows down the compiled code?

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, compile

I made a routine code `CodeComp2` that performs algebraic evaluations using some data  `TablexgridWithEx`, `TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts` and a few analytic expressions: `pproductLab1Spher`, `pproductLab3Spher`, `pproductLab2Spher`, `EproductLabSpher` (the first group), and `coordProj1`, `coordProj2` (the second group). Inside the code, some values that use the first group of expressions are evaluated first, and then they are inserted in the formulas from the second group. Because of some reason, the second step takes a lot of time, although the expressions from the first group itself look simpler than the first group.

What may be the reason for this slowdown, and how to fix the code?

These are the relevant analytic expressions:

```
phVal[px_, py_] = 
  If[py > 0, 
   ArcCos[px/(\[Sqrt](px^2 + py^2))], -ArcCos[
     px/(\[Sqrt](px^2 + py^2))]];
thVal[px_, py_, pz_] = ArcCos[pz/(\[Sqrt](px^2 + py^2 + pz^2))];
pMotherVecSpher[Ex_, mx_, thx_, phx_] = 
  Sqrt[Ex^2 - mx^2] {Sin[thx]*Cos[phx], Sin[thx]*Sin[phx], Cos[thx]};
vMotherVecSpher[Ex_, mx_, thx_, phx_] = +(
   pMotherVecSpher[Ex, mx, thx, phx]/Ex);
\[Gamma]Factor[Ex_, mx_] = Ex/mx;
\[CapitalGamma]factor[Ex_, mx_] = 
  Simplify[(\[Gamma]Factor[Ex, mx] - 
    1)/((v /. 
      Solve[\[Gamma]Factor[Ex, mx] == 1/Sqrt[1 - v^2], v])^2)[[1]]];
pproductRestVec[Eprodrest_, mprod_, thprodrest_, phprodrest_] = 
  Sqrt[Eprodrest^2 - mprod^2] {Sin[thprodrest]*Cos[phprodrest], 
    Sin[thprodrest]*Sin[phprodrest], Cos[thprodrest]};
pproductLabVecSpher[Ex_, mx_, thx_, phx_, Eprodrest_, mprod_, 
   thprodrest_, phprodrest_] = 
  Simplify[
   pproductRestVec[Eprodrest, mprod, thprodrest, 
     phprodrest] + \[Gamma]Factor[Ex, mx]*
     vMotherVecSpher[Ex, mx, thx, phx]*
     Eprodrest + \[CapitalGamma]factor[Ex, mx]*
     vMotherVecSpher[Ex, mx, thx, 
      phx] (vMotherVecSpher[Ex, mx, thx, phx] . 
       pproductRestVec[Eprodrest, mprod, thprodrest, phprodrest])];
EproductLabSpher[Ex_, mx_, thx_, phx_, Eprodrest_, mprod_, 
   thprodrest_, phprodrest_] = 
  Simplify[\[Gamma]Factor[Ex, 
     mx] (Eprodrest + 
      vMotherVecSpher[Ex, mx, thx, phx] . 
       pproductRestVec[Eprodrest, mprod, thprodrest, phprodrest])];
pproductLab1Spher[Ex_, mx_, thx_, phx_, Eprodrest_, mprod_, 
   thprodrest_, phprodrest_] = 
  pproductLabVecSpher[Ex, mx, thx, phx, Eprodrest, mprod, thprodrest, 
    phprodrest][[1]];
pproductLab2Spher[Ex_, mx_, thx_, phx_, Eprodrest_, mprod_, 
   thprodrest_, phprodrest_] = 
  pproductLabVecSpher[Ex, mx, thx, phx, Eprodrest, mprod, thprodrest, 
    phprodrest][[2]];
pproductLab3Spher[Ex_, mx_, thx_, phx_, Eprodrest_, mprod_, 
   thprodrest_, phprodrest_] = 
  pproductLabVecSpher[Ex, mx, thx, phx, Eprodrest, mprod, thprodrest, 
    phprodrest][[3]];
xyzPointxvertex[xLongx_, thx_, phx_] = {(xLongx/Sin[phx])*Cos[phx], 
   xLongx, (xLongx/(Sin[thx]*Sin[phx]))*Cos[thx]};
xyzPointxvertexX[xLongx_, thx_, phx_] = 
  xyzPointxvertex[xLongx, thx, phx][[1]];
xyzPointxvertexSecondCoordinate[xLongx_, thx_, phx_] = 
  xyzPointxvertex[xLongx, thx, phx][[3]];
xLongDecayProductFinalPlaneGivenExperiment = 85;
xyzPointDaughterProjection[xLongx_, thx_, phx_, px_, py_, 
   pz_] = {xyzPointxvertex[xLongx, thx, phx][[
     1]] + (xLongDecayProductFinalPlaneGivenExperiment - xLongx) (px/
       py), xLongDecayProductFinalPlaneGivenExperiment, 
   xyzPointxvertex[xLongx, thx, phx][[
     3]] + (xLongDecayProductFinalPlaneGivenExperiment - xLongx) (pz/
       py)};
coordProj1[xLongx_, thx_, phx_, px_, py_, pz_] = 
  If[py > 0, 
   Evaluate[
    xyzPointDaughterProjection[xLongx, thx, phx, px, py, pz][[1]]], 
   99999];
coordProj2[xLongx_, thx_, phx_, px_, py_, pz_] = 
  If[py > 0, 
   Evaluate[
    xyzPointDaughterProjection[xLongx, thx, phx, px, py, pz][[3]]], 
   99999];
```

Next, there is an example data:

```
mxval = 2;
TablexgridWithEx = 
  Tuples[{RandomReal[{mxval, 10^4}, 100] // Sort, 
    RandomReal[{0.33, 0.94}, 50] // Sort, 
    RandomReal[{60, 85}, 40] // Sort, 
    RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, 40] // Sort}];
indexEx = 1;
indexxLongx = 3;
indexthx = 3;
indexphx = 4;
indexEprod1rest = 1;
indexthprod1rest = 2;
indexphprod1rest = 3;
indexEprod2rest = 4;
indexthprod2rest = 5;
indexphprod2rest = 6;
mproduct1 = mproduct2 = 0.5;
nprod = 10;
RandomDir = RandomPoint[Sphere[], nprod];
TabProduct1Rest = 
  Join[Table[{(mxval^2 - mproduct2^2 + mproduct1^2)/(2 mxval)}, 
    nprod], {ArcCos[#[[3]]], phVal[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} & /@ RandomDir, 2];
TabProduct2Rest = 
  Join[Table[{(mxval^2 + mproduct2^2 - mproduct1^2)/(2 mxval)}, 
    nprod], {ArcCos[-#[[3]]], phVal[-#[[1]], -#[[2]]]} & /@ RandomDir,
    2];
TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts = 
  Join[TabProduct1Rest, TabProduct2Rest, 2];
```

Finally, there is the block `CodeComp2` compiling evaluations:

```
CodeComp2 = 
  Hold@Compile[{{TablexgridWithEx, _Real, 
                    1}, {TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts, _Real, 
                    2}, {mx, _Real}, {mproduct1, _Real}, {mproduct2, \
_Real}},
                    
                    Module[{cond, count, FirstCoordinateProduct1, 
                    SecondCoordinateProduct1, FirstCoordinateProduct2,
                     SecondCoordinateProduct2, EnergyProduct1, 
                    EnergyProduct2, ex, xlongx, thx, phx, eprod1rest, 
                    thprod1rest, phprod1rest, eprod2rest, thprod2rest,
                     phprod2rest, pxprod1lab, pxprod2lab, pyprod1lab, 
                    pyprod2lab, pzprod1lab, pzprod2lab, \[Epsilon]Azx},
                    count = 0.;
                    ex = Compile`GetElement[TablexgridWithEx, indexEx];
                    
                    xlongx = 
                    Compile`GetElement[TablexgridWithEx, 
                    indexxLongx];
                    
                    thx = Compile`GetElement[TablexgridWithEx, 
                    indexthx];
                    
                    phx = Compile`GetElement[TablexgridWithEx, 
                    indexphx];
                    Do[
                    
                    eprod1rest = 
                    Compile`GetElement[TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts, 
                    j, indexEprod1rest];
                    
                    thprod1rest = 
                    Compile`GetElement[TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts, 
                    j, indexthprod1rest];
                    
                    phprod1rest = 
                    Compile`GetElement[TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts, 
                    j, indexphprod1rest];
                    
                    eprod2rest = 
                    Compile`GetElement[TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts, 
                    j, indexEprod2rest];
                    
                    thprod2rest = 
                    Compile`GetElement[TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts, 
                    j, indexthprod2rest];
                    
                    phprod2rest = 
                    Compile`GetElement[TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts, 
                    j, indexphprod2rest];
                    (*Where I use formulas that are evaluated fast*)
                    
                    pxprod1lab = 
                    pproductLab1Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod1rest, 
                    mproduct1, thprod1rest, phprod1rest];
                    
                    pyprod1lab = 
                    pproductLab2Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod1rest, 
                    mproduct1, thprod1rest, phprod1rest];
                    
                    pzprod1lab = 
                    pproductLab3Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod1rest, 
                    mproduct1, thprod1rest, phprod1rest];
                    
                    pxprod2lab = 
                    pproductLab1Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod2rest, 
                    mproduct2, thprod2rest, phprod2rest];
                    
                    pyprod2lab = 
                    pproductLab2Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod2rest, 
                    mproduct2, thprod2rest, phprod2rest];
                    
                    pzprod2lab = 
                    pproductLab3Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod2rest, 
                    mproduct2, thprod2rest, phprod2rest];
                    
                    EnergyProduct1 = 
                    EproductLabSpher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod1rest, 
                    mproduct1, thprod1rest, phprod1rest];
                    
                    EnergyProduct2 = 
                    EproductLabSpher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod2rest, 
                    mproduct2, thprod2rest, phprod2rest];
                    (*Where I use formulas that are evaluated slow*)
                    
                    FirstCoordinateProduct1 = 
                    coordProj1[xlongx, thx, phx, pxprod1lab, 
                    pyprod1lab, pzprod1lab];
                    
                    SecondCoordinateProduct1 = 
                    coordProj2[xlongx, thx, phx, pxprod1lab, 
                    pyprod1lab, pzprod1lab];
                    
                    FirstCoordinateProduct2 = 
                    coordProj1[xlongx, thx, phx, pxprod2lab, 
                    pyprod2lab, pzprod2lab];
                    
                    SecondCoordinateProduct2 = 
                    coordProj2[xlongx, thx, phx, pxprod2lab, 
                    pyprod2lab, pzprod2lab]
                    , {j, 1, Length[TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts]}];
                    {count/Length[TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts]}
                    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
                    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
                    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
                    Parallelization -> True] /. 
                   DownValues@coordProj1 /. DownValues@coordProj2 /. 
                 DownValues@pproductLab1Spher /. 
                DownValues@pproductLab2Spher /. 
               DownValues@pproductLab3Spher /. 
              DownValues@EproductLabSpher /. OwnValues@indexEx /. 
            OwnValues@indexxLongx /. OwnValues@indexthx /. 
          OwnValues@indexphx /. OwnValues@indexEprod1rest /. 
        OwnValues@indexthprod1rest /. OwnValues@indexphprod1rest /. 
      OwnValues@indexEprod2rest /. OwnValues@indexthprod2rest /. 
    OwnValues@indexphprod2rest // ReleaseHold;
```

The block has rows evaluating values using the functions `pproductLab1Spher`,`pproductLab2Spher`,`pproductLab3Spher`,`EproductLabSpher`, which are then inserted in `coordProj1`,`coordProj2`. The first functions look much more complicated than the second ones:

[image]

Let us first comment the following rows calling `coordProj1`, `coordProj2`:

```
FirstCoordinateProduct1 = 
 coordProj1[xlongx, thx, phx, pprod1lab, py1lab, pz1lab];
SecondCoordinateProduct1 = 
 coordProj2[xlongx, thx, phx, pprod1lab, py1lab, pz1lab];
FirstCoordinateProduct2 = 
 coordProj1[xlongx, thx, phx, pprod2lab, py2lab, pz2lab];
SecondCoordinateProduct2 = 
 coordProj2[xlongx, thx, phx, pprod2lab, py2lab, pz2lab]
```

Then

```
CodeComp2[TablexgridWithEx, TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts, mxval, 
   mproduct1, mproduct2]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.307338, Null}

Next, let us uncomment them:

> {2.80388, Null}

The slowdown is ~10 times!

I have checked that the `If` condition in `coordProj` is not the main reason for the performance problem. Moreover, the rows using the first group of formulas (`pproductLab1Spher`, etc.; starting from `pxprod1lab =` ) take negligible time to evaluate. To see this, let us comment the rows

```
pxprod1lab = pproductLab1Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod1rest, mproduct1, thprod1rest, phprod1rest];
pyprod1lab = pproductLab2Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod1rest, mproduct1, thprod1rest, phprod1rest];
pzprod1lab = pproductLab3Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod1rest, mproduct1, thprod1rest, phprod1rest];
pxprod2lab = pproductLab1Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod2rest, mproduct2, thprod2rest, phprod2rest];
pyprod2lab = pproductLab2Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod2rest, mproduct2, thprod2rest, phprod2rest];
pzprod2lab = pproductLab3Spher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod2rest, mproduct2, thprod2rest, phprod2rest];
EnergyProduct1 = EproductLabSpher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod1rest, mproduct1, thprod1rest, phprod1rest];
EnergyProduct2 = EproductLabSpher[ex, mx, thx, phx, eprod2rest, mproduct2, thprod2rest, phprod2rest];
(*Where I use formulas that are evaluated slow*)
FirstCoordinateProduct1 = coordProj1[xlongx, thx, phx, pxprod1lab, pyprod1lab, pzprod1lab];
SecondCoordinateProduct1 = coordProj2[xlongx, thx, phx, pxprod1lab, 
pyprod1lab, pzprod1lab];
FirstCoordinateProduct2 = coordProj1[xlongx, thx, phx, pxprod2lab, 
pyprod2lab, pzprod2lab];
SecondCoordinateProduct2 = coordProj2[xlongx, thx, phx, pxprod2lab, pyprod2lab, pzprod2lab]
```

> {0.284096, Null}

-- comparable with the evaluation time if commenting only `FirstCoordinateProduct1 = ...`.

So the relative slowdown caused by `FirstCoordinateProduct1 = ...` is actually much larger.

**Edit**

Following the answer by Domen.

Even if replacing the trigonometric formulas for `coordProj1`, `coordProj2` with simple

```
coordProj1[xLongx_, thx_, phx_, px_, py_, pz_] =   xLongx*thx*phx*px*py*pz; 
coordProj2[xLongx_, thx_, phx_, px_, py_, pz_] =   xLongx*thx*phx*px*py*pz;
```

the evaluation of `CodeComp2` with uncommented rows still takes much longer time (0.7 seconds) than the evaluation with the commented rows (0.3 seconds), which again means a huge slowdown required to evaluate, e.g., `FirstCoordinateProduct1` compared to the evaluation of, e.g., `pxprod1lab` (up to a 100 times longer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it looks like your second formulae are "simpler" than the first ones, they contain two problematic functions: `Csc[x]` and `Cot[x]`, which somehow happen to be **significantly** slower when compiled than all `Sin`, `Cos`, `Sqrt` that are present in the previous formulae.

Let me convince you:

```
opts = {CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"};

sin = Compile[{{xs, _Real, 1}}, Do[Sin[x], {x, xs}], Evaluate@{opts}];
sqrt = Compile[{{xs, _Real, 1}}, Do[Sqrt[x], {x, xs}], Evaluate@{opts}];
cos = Compile[{{xs, _Real, 1}}, Do[Cos[x], {x, xs}], Evaluate@{opts}];
cot = Compile[{{xs, _Real, 1}}, Do[Cot[x], {x, xs}], Evaluate@{opts}];
csc = Compile[{{xs, _Real, 1}}, Do[Csc[x], {x, xs}], Evaluate@{opts}];
recSin = Compile[{{xs, _Real, 1}}, Do[1/Sin[x], {x, xs}], Evaluate@{opts}];
recTan = Compile[{{xs, _Real, 1}}, Do[1/Tan[x], {x, xs}], Evaluate@{opts}];

xs = RandomReal[1, 10000000];
{#, Module[{f = ToExpression[#]}, 
     First@AbsoluteTiming[f[xs];]]} & /@ {"sin", "cos", "sqrt", "cot",
    "csc", "recSin", "recTan"} // Column
```

```
sin     0.0000221
cos     2.1*10^-6
sqrt    1.8*10^-6
cot     0.223804
csc     0.153003
recSin  4.*10^-6
recTan  2.1*10^-6
```

Therefore, use `SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False]` and use replacements* `/. Cot[x_] :> 1/Tan[x]` and `/. Csc[x_] :> 1/Sin[x]` in your formulae. I tried it on your code, and it worked.

---

* I am not an expert in numerical calculations, so you should check yourself that using reciprocal values does not affect the stability and accuracy of your calculations.

Comment: Thanks! I will check. However, what still disturbs me is that even if replacing these trigonometric formulas with simple `coordProj1[xLongx_, thx_, phx_, px_, py_, pz_] =
  xLongx*thx*phx*px*py*pz;
coordProj2[xLongx_, thx_, phx_, px_, py_, pz_] =
  xLongx*thx*phx*px*py*pz;`, the evaluation of the corresponding rows in `CodeComp2` still takes much-much longer than the evaluation of the rows `pxprod1lab = ...` (~0.01 second for the latter vs 0.4 seconds for the former+the latter on my machine). Do you have any ideas about the reason?

Comment: By 0.01 second, I mean the relative timing between the computation of `CodeComp2` with commented rows `FirstCoordinateProduct1 = ...` and similar, and the one with, in addition, commented rows `pxprod1lab = ...` and similar.

Comment: Hm, are you sure you cleared the variables properly? If I use this simple definitions for `coordProj1` and `coordProj2`, I get practically the same results for both bases (with or without "slow" formulas). (It's quite a long code, so it might also be me evaluating some wrongly ...)

Comment: yes, I started with a fresh kernel. ~0.69 seconds for the full evaluation on Mathematica 13.1@Windows 10 Enterprise, versus 0.28 for the evaluation with commented `FirstCoordinateProduct1 = ...`

Comment: [My screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cic8J.png) – Also, I might have lost track of your updates, and perhaps I have to reread your question again ...

Comment: Excuse me, I have a dumb habit to edit the question body after asking. However, I did not make serious corrections.

Comment: I have once again copied your [whole code](https://pastebin.com/43Zj3MTy) and used simplified `coordProj1/2` without trigs. There is still only [a slight increase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUWvs.png) in time when I compare funcs with or without the problematic four lines. Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: No, it seems that I had a problem on my side related to cache maybe.

Comment: I understood what caused the slowdown on my side. I accidentally did not comment the first row `FirstCoordinateProduct1 =...`... May I please ask you probably a similar question? Why if adding `count += FirstCoordinateProduct1` to `CodeComp2` I significantly slow down the code (0.9 seconds vs 0.3 seconds)? This is a pure summation, I thought it should be fast...

Comment: The problem is not present if e.g. I add `count += 1.`.

Comment: It is not the `count += FirstCoordinateProduct1` that is the problem, it is the line when you return values (`{count/Length[TablePhaseSpaceDecayProducts]}`) because you are getting overflows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145549/discussion-between-domen-and-john-taylor).